# I receive this error "error: expected ';' at end of declaration" when trying to compile in VSC. How can I fix this issue?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I recently updated my c++ extension and VSC and I'm in a college class for C++ programming. My teacher instantiates a class in main like this

`Course c1{};`

and when I follow his lead and go to compile I receive an error `error: expected ';' at end of declaration`. If I remove the curly braces and rerun its just fine. However, I'd like to know if there is a way to make it so I can follow my teachers example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Course {
    public:
        string name;
};

void setName(Course &c, string n) {
    c.name = n;
}

void output(Course &c) {
    cout << c.name << endl;
}

int main() {
    Course c1{}; // Here is where I attempt to create a class along with the curly braces.
    cout << &c1 << endl;

    setName(c1, "ET580");
    output(c1);

    Course c2;
    cout << &c2 << endl;
    setName(c2, "ET574");
    output(c2);

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It compiles perfectly in my IDE and also shows the output maybe there is another problem.

Comment: Try compiling the code with `std=c++11` flag.

Comment: how do i add a flag? is this compatible with VSC?